# Is disabling secureboot that bad?

Tags: linux, usb, windows-11, bootable-media, secure-boot

I want to sometimes use Linux, sometimes windows.

I found out that, Puppy Linux is small, I can install it on a USB. But the problem is, if I click on my USB in the boot menu, I have to disable secure boot first.

I was looking for something about disabling secure boot and found something interesting:

> Secure Boot must be enabled before an operating system is installed. If an operating system was installed while Secure Boot was disabled, it will not support Secure Boot and a new installation is required.

My questions are:

If I disabled secure boot, installed Linux on the USB and enabled it again, will it affect my Windows 11?

Can I update Windows with secure boot disabled and enable it again?

Is somehow possible to make the USB bootable with Secure Boot enabled?

Comment: A couple of options. There are [instructions](https://helledussen.com/linux/files/UEFI_boot/make_uefi-bootable_usb.html) for making a secure boot puppy linux usb image. Another option is to run puppy in a virtual machine using hyper-v, virtualbox, etc. Your VM can be run in full-screen mode so you have full functionality.

Comment: @doneal24
1) I have to disable secure boot first to boot the usb when following the instructions
2) VM is slower, less convenient

Comment: The instructions work in my environment, what errors do you encounter? Also, since Puppy is so lightweight, I’m surprised that the VM is noticeably slower. Once it’s booted into memory it should run very quickly. Only things slowing it down would be background Windows services.

Comment: @doneal24, >There are instructions for making a secure boot puppy linux usb image<

No, this is instruction on how to create UEFI-bootable image. It says to disable Secure Boot on the linked page.

Comment: Interesting, I don’t see the word disable anywhere in the page. It does give instructions on creating the uefi partition and has you select the boot device from bios. Never says to disable secure boot. Can you give a quote supporting your statement?

Comment: A full-fledged Ubuntu bootable USB can run with Secure Boot enabled, though I've no experience with Puppy OS. If you create a *persistent* image on the USB (https://www.howtogeek.com/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/), you can keep any changes made as well as data. **Caveat:** Most flash USB drives are far slower than even a HDD, and disk operations suffer. *If* you can boot from a portable SSD, it should be much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLOSED:
Installed Ubuntu dual-boot instead...